# UITableViewDataSource method

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, methods, protocols

Here is the **CellForRowAtIndexPath** method of **UITableViewDataSource** protocol. I saw that code on a website.

```
    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        static NSString *TableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:TableIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:TableIdentifier];
        }

        cell.textLabel.text = [playersReady objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return cell;
}
```

***My questions are:***

1. Why when here defined `cell` wrote `= [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:TableIdentifier];` ? What that means? If I commented that code everything going OK. **For what that code?** Hmmm...
2. How `cell` in `if` statement can be equals to `nil` if `cell` equals to `TableIdentifier` (**SimpleTableItem**)? **For what wrote that code?**
3. Why `TableIdentifier` equals to **SimpleTableItem**? **For What?**

Comment: You can find all the information here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An iPhone doesn't have a lot of memory. But even on modern computers you wouldn't want to initialize a new cell for *every* cell in your table. That's just wasting memory. So instead Apple came up with this idea of reusable cells. You only have to initialize a few cells that fill your screen (table view). Then, when the user scrolls down some new cells will appear at the bottom of the screen, but at the same time other cells will disappear at the top of the screen. So you can simply take those cells and reuse them.

Luckily UITableView manages this for you. All you have to do when you need to setup a new cell in that method is ask the table view, if it has any cells available that can be reused. If there are reusable cells, dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: will return one of them. But if there are non available yet (typically when you first fill up your table view with the initial cells) it will return nil. So you have to test if cell is nil and create a new cell from scratch if that's the case.

On iOS 6.0 there is a new method `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` that always returns a valid cell (it creates the cell for you if there is no reusable cell yet).

Answer (score 1):

Table view Create only those cell which can Display at one time on screen.After this system reuse cell for save memory .

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return 20;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViewL cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";


UITableViewCell *cell = [tableViewL dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) 
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    NSLog(@"Cell == nil so create a new cell....");

}else {
     NSLog(@"Reuse Cell ");
}
 return cell;

}
```

CellIdentifier use for identify cell for example if you add label on first ten table on 12 cell you add a button it give you a problem when you  reuse cell.so that we need create a different cell For add button on cell and give it a Identifier string.